# KeyError when passing kwargs to ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a custom field for my M2M field in my ModelForm. `ConnectedTo` is the many to many field. Code below:

views:

```
def addPartForm_Create(request, site, subtype):
    siteselected = site
    sitenumber = str(site)
    print(sitenumber)
    subtypeselected = Subtype.objects.get(SubtypeID = subtype)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addPartForm(request.POST, sitenum=sitenumber)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.SiteID = Site.objects.get(SiteID = siteselected)
            obj.Subtype = subtypeselected
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('/sites/'+str(site))
    else:
        form = addPartForm()
    return render(request, 'myproj/addPart.html', {'form': form, 'SiteNo': Site.objects.get(SiteID = siteselected).SiteID, 'subtype': subtypeselected})
```

forms:

```
class addPartForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Part
    fields = ('Comment', 'Location', 'ConnectedTo', 'BatchNo', 'Manufacturer', 'Length', 'InspectionPeriod')
    labels = {"BatchNo": "Batch Number", "InspectionPeriod": "Inspection Period"}


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(addPartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    sitenum = kwargs.pop('sitenum')
    self.fields["ConnectedTo"].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    self.fields["ConnectedTo"].queryset = Part.objects.filter(SiteID = sitenum)
```

I get KeyError when I try to pass sitenum from view to form. I know I could set a default value None but I don't want it to ever display none. I need to always have a sitenum sent here. Am I passing this wrong?

Comment: You need to check if `ConnectedTo` in fields before altering the field. `if 'ConnectedTo' in fields:`

Comment: Tried that. Nothing different

Comment: Ahhh, I got it. Sorry, I didn't read the last sentence first. Check if `sitenum` in `kwargs` before trying to pop it. Looks like you will have cases where it wasn't passed, so you'd need to get it elsewhere

Comment: Don't just say "I get KeyError", show the full error trace. That will tell you which line of code exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: Also, if `request.method == 'GET'`, you initialise your form without `sitenum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the kwarg sitenum to all instances of your form, you aren't doing this when the request is GET. I'd also move all kwargs.pop() above the super calls to ensure it doesn't conflict with kwargs that the super might be expecting.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This was really helpful